# Handing over locked std::unique_lock to new threads

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, language-lawyer, mutex

Consider the following example where I create a `std::mutex`, lock it and then hand the lock over to another thread :

```
#include <future>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    // Create and lock a mutex
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);

    // Hand off the lock to another thread
    auto promise = std::async(std::launch::async, 
        [lock{ std::move(lock) }]() mutable
        {
            // Unlock the mutex
            lock.unlock();
        });

    promise.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The example seems to run fine with gcc 6.3 but fails an run-time assert with Visual Studio 2015 with the error *"unlock of unowned mutex"*.

I've noticed that if I switch the example to use [`std::shared_timed_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) and [`std::shared_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) then the example completes successfully. I've also noticed that if I remove the explicit `unlock` then the example completes successfully, but the mutex doesn't seem to unlock at all (crashes with VC if I try to lock the mutex again, gcc doesn't complain).

Based on what I read on cppreference.com about [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) it seems to me like the original example should run fine. Does something about `std::mutex` or `std::unique_lock` forbid a thread to `unlock` if another thread did the `lock`? Is this perhaps a VC bug?

Comment: It is unrelated to `std::unique_lock` which just calls lock/unlock on a mutex, but mutex itself.

Comment: Use semaphores!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock :

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The documentation for `std::shared_timed_mutex::unlock()` has the same specification, so it's not guaranteed to work with that class either.

Comment: I would use different words rather than "not guaranteed to work"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux most probably you have XY problem

Comment: @Slava I get around the problem by passing a reference to the mutex to the `async` function and taking another lock from there. It's fine if someone else steals the mutex in between, just feels like a waste to unlock a mutex you know you will immediately need. I was just curious as to why the original approach didn't work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it does not work because most probably your locking logic is flawed, hense XY problem. But you do not provide enough details to say more.